# Массив неизвестного происхождения

Tags: массивы, php

Доброго всем времени суток господа

есть такая запись в бд:

```
a:5:{s:3:"pos";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}s:8:"replwhat";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"5";}s:3:"tip";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}s:6:"length";s:1:"6";s:8:"supplier";s:12:"testbrand712";}
```

- может я от жизни отстал, или не знаю все языки программирования, но достаточно часто встречаю такую структуру хранения данных. Может кто подсказать откуда это добро, что это за язык или метод хранения? И как это преобразовать в массив PHP ? Ну и обратно.. может я на это подсяду ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[[@fori1ton](/users/5577/fori1ton)](/users/5577/fori1ton), никто ничего не изобретал )) По крайней мере, для этой записи ;)

```
$str = 'a:5:{s:3:"pos";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"1";}s:8:"replwhat";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"5";}s:3:"tip";a:1:{i:0;s:1:"2";}s:6:"length";s:1:"6";s:8:"supplier";s:12:"testbrand712";}';
$res = unserialize($str);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($res);
echo '</pre>';
```

Имеем следующее:

```
Array
(
    [pos] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
        )

    [replwhat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 5
        )

    [tip] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
        )

    [length] => 6
    [supplier] => testbrand712
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы сильно отстали от жизни или не знаете JavaScript. Это [JSON](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON). Конвертация из JSON в ассоциативный массив осуществляется функцией [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php), обратно - [`json_encode`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: Блин, а я склеиваю это и расклеиваю каждый раз )) Спасибо!

Comment: Прошу прощения, я ошибся. Этот формат похож на JSON, но не является им. Кто-то изобрёл JSON-подобный велосипед и записал в вашу базу.

Comment: от оно че, Михалыч )) Ну я написал, что часто такое видел, значит наверняка в 99% случаев мне это поможет